# Find all the Anagrams, and the Subanagrams too!

Tags: code-golf, string, permutations

This question is heavily based off [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/125879/find-all-the-anagrams), but should pose a number of additional difficulties.

### Your Task

You must write a program or function that, when receiving a string, prints out all possible anagrams of it.  For the purpose of this question, an anagram is a string that contains the same character as the original string, but is not the original string.  A subanagram is an anagram of a substring of an inputted string.  Anagrams and subanagrams do not have to be or contain actual words.

### Input

You may accept a string, which may be of any length > 0, by any standard input method.  It may contain any ASCII characters.

### Output

You may output all of the possible anagrams and subanagrams of the inputted string in any standard way. You must not output the same string twice, or output a string equal to the input.

### Other Rules

[Standard Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are disallowed

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), least bytes wins.

Comment: Is the empty string a possible anagram?

Comment: Is outputting the original string/sustrings allowed?

Comment: @CalculatorFeline "You must not output the same string twice, or output a string equal to the input."

Comment: @DigitalTrauma, "You may accept a string, *which may be of any length > 0*, by any standard input method".  (emphasis added)

Comment: Some Test cases would be helpful

Comment: _"an anagram is a string that contains the same character as the original string, but is not the original string"_: it's unclear to me whether it applies to subanagrams as well (in which case `AB` is not a valid subanagram of `ABCD`, but `BA` is). Could you please clarify?

Comment: Should `tt` be an anagram of `test`? If yes, then quite some given solutions are not working. If not, then I guess that `aa` shouldn't be an anagram of `aabb` and again some solutions are not working. Some examples to explain this would be helpful :)

Comment: No, tt is not an anagram or a subanagram of "test".  However, I never specifically said you couldn't output additional strings, which was a mistake in the question.  I just said you couldn't output the same string twice, which I don't think any answer is doing, or output the original string, which I also don't think any answer is doing.  I would change the question to not allow substrings of the input, but it's too late now, as that would invalidate existing answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/docs/code-page.md)

```
Œ€œ˜Ù¹K
```

A function that accepts a string from input and leaves a list of strings on the stack. As a full program a representation of the list is printed.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARwA4/8wNWFiMWX//8WS4oKsxZPLnMOZwrlL//90ZXh0)**

#### How?

```
        - push input
Œ       - all substrings
 €œ     - for €ach: all permutations
   ˜    - flatten
    Ù   - de-duplicate
     ¹  - push 1st input onto top of stack
      K - pop a,b; push a without any b's (remove the copy of the input from the list)
        - as a full program: implicit print of the top of the stack
```

Comment: And... you managed something even shorter.

Comment: It's the same algorithm, just less bytes.

Comment: Yes, the language change was all, but its still impressive.

Comment: @ais523 Looks like I got both the wrong way around!

Comment: @ais523 I think that it is fixed.

Answer (score 9):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog) (2), 7 bytes

```
{sp}ᶠdb
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/v7q4oPbhtgUpSf//KyUmJaakKv2PAgA)

### Explanation

```
{sp}ᶠdb
{  }ᶠ    Find all
  p        permutations of
 s         a substring of {the input}
     d   Remove duplicates (leaving the list otherwise in the same order)
      b  Remove the first (the input itself)
```

Comment: What does the (2) mean?

Comment: @Gryphon (afaik) there are 2 versions of branchylog, this is using V2.

Comment: Ok, wasn't sure if it was version number or a possible byte count using a different, and possibly illegal method.

Comment: That's the second time I've been asked now. I guess I'll have to start writing it as `(v2)`.

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ẆŒ!€;/QḟW
```

A monadic link accepting a list and returning a list of all distinct sub-anagrams except the input itself.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9qZWxsef//4bqGxZIh4oKsOy9R4bifV//Dh1n//3RleHQ)** (the footer pretty-prints the resulting list by joining with newlines.)

#### How?

```
ẆŒ!€;/QḟW - Link: list of characters, s
Ẇ         - all contiguous sublists of s
 Œ!€      - all permutations for €ach sublist now a list of lists of lists)
     /    - reduce by:
    ;     -   concatenation (flattens the list by one level)
      Q   - de-duplicate (gets the unique entries)
        W - wrap s in a list (otherwise filtering will attempt to remove characters)
       ḟ  - filter discard from left if in right (remove the one equal to the input)
```

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, 12

```
-{.n.pM.:Q)]
```

[Online test](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=-%7B.n.pM.%3AQ%29%5D&input=%27aabc%27&debug=0).

```
         Q       # input
       .: )      # all substrings
    .pM          # all permutations of all substrings
  .n             # flatten
 {               # deduplicate
-          ]Q    # subtract (list of) (implicit) input
```

Comment: @ais523 Redone - I think it is correct now.

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 10 bytes

```
à má c â Å
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///AChdzDCxWSFQ4vUjjc@v@/UmJSohIA)

I got to use `à`, `á`, and `â` all in one answer, in order too. What a coincidence...

#### Explanation

```
 à má c â Å
Uà má c â s1  // Ungolfed
              // Implicit: U = input string
Uà            // Take all combinations of characters in the input string.
   má         // Map each combination to all of its permutations.
      c       // Flatten into a single array.
        â     // Uniquify; remove all duplicates.
          s1  // Remove the first item (the input) from the resulting array.
              // Implicit: output resulting array, separated by commas
```

Comment: You even managed Å too.

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica, 60 bytes

```
DeleteCases[""<>#&/@Permutations[c=Characters@#,Tr[1^c]],#]&
```

`Permutations` takes an optional numerical argument which tells it how many of the input values to use for the permutations. If we give it the length of the input, it will generate the permutations for all subsets of the input without duplicates. All we need to do is remove the input.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>313</s> <s>312</s> <s>306</s> 297 bytes

```java
import java.util.*;s->{Set l=new HashSet();for(int z=s.length(),i=0,j;i<z;i++)for(j=i;j<z;)p("",s.substring(i,++j),l);l.remove(s);l.forEach(System.out::println);}void p(String p,String s,Set l){int n=s.length(),i=0;if(n<1)l.add(p);for(;i<n;p(p+s.charAt(i),s.substring(0,i)+s.substring(++i,n),l));}
```

Modified version of [my answer here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/125953/52210), where `p("",s,l);` has been replaced with `for(int z=s.length(),i=0,j;i<z;i++)for(j=i;j<z;p("",s.substring(i,j+++1),l));`

-6 bytes thanks to *@OlivierGrégoire* in my linked answer
-9 bytes thanks to *@ceilingcat*

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##XZBBb8IgFMfvfoqXnWAg6nFil@ywZJd58Wg8UIqWjgIp1EWNn72Dqsm2BAL/F97jl18jjmLqvLJN9TXo1rsuQpNqrI/asGcOMJsBWbxAdBBrBeUpqql0vY0TaUQI8Cm0vUwAtI2q2wupYJ0jwNHpCiTaxE7bAwTMU/WadlprsFDAEKavl42KYAqrvuFDhDolhPnedSiNg3MRmFH2EGuEqS7mtOF6deaaEJyfNIXmTcrYo6cnGljoyzB@hjQlpMHUYG5Yp1p3VCjke@p6F7JGm1OIqmWuj8ulTx3RWMyvfCT2D2JPH@h0hMSXzGT/MXG9R3a1wIaJqkL@Bp8wLffIk8BkLbq3iDT@AzinGpPfBUI0tZk4cQwAvi@NlhCiiOkYudrk@Y623YHAN8nZPrRJZjaYAxo9A7TMMonEdr67i78OgyhL@QM)

**Explanation of this part:**

```java
for(int z=s.length(),i=0,j;i<z;i++) // Loop `i` in the range [0,length):
  for(j=i;j<z;)                     //  Inner loop `j` in the range [i,length):
    p("",                           //   Call the permutation-method,
      s.substring(i,++j),l));       //   with a substring at index-range [i,j]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 9 bytes

```
ǎƛṖ;fU'⁰≠
```

### Explanation

```
<implicit input>
ǎ                 - Get substrings
 ƛṖ;              - Map over substrings: Get permutations
    f             - Flatten it
     U            - Uniquify, remove all duplicates
      '⁰≠         - Filter lambda: Keep all elements that don't equal input
<implicit output>
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C7%8E%C6%9B%E1%B9%96%3BfU%27%E2%81%B0%E2%89%A0&inputs=Abcde&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 75 bytes

```perl6
{unique(flat $_,.comb.combinations.skip».permutations.map(*».join)).skip}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##LYw7CgIxEEB7TzGFSCIy5TbiWSSbzMJofiYZQWRPtp0XixJsXvF4vEzFT10qwXNCe96FFxxscgSX/pbIDyG1eNNgfz2hTWEe4Ggap1ix3jl/NsxUgrS/Cyar40/eEketR7J2HFPM0mBJBTxHqkp3M1vnvg)

### Expanded:

```perl6
{                    # bare block lambda with implicit parameter ｢$_｣

  unique(            # return each (sub)anagram once

    flat             # unstructure the following (List of Lists into flat List)
      $_,            # the input (so we can skip it at the end)

      .comb          # split the input into graphemes
      .combinations  # get all the combinations
      .skip\         # skip the first empty combination
      ».permutations # get all the permutations of each combination
      .map(*».join)  # join the inner permutations

  ).skip             # skip the first value (the input)
}
```